# Modifying a 2d Array within a recursive function, C

Tags: c, string, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to recursively modify a 2D char array (array of strings), but after the first recursive call the array returns blank even though the changes register in the base case

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

int height;
printf("Enter the height of your triangle.\n");
scanf("%d", &height);


printf("Lets see if you were successful!\n");
fractalTriangle(height, 1);

}

void fractalTriangle (int height, int fractalLevel) {

//has to make the array and do the printing all in the same function
char trianglePattern [height][2 * height - 1];

if (fractalLevel == 0) {
    int rowSize = 2 * height - 1;
    char rowString[rowSize]; //string to store in pattern's array
    int asteriskCount = 1; //number of asterisks printed in each row
    int spaces = (rowSize - asteriskCount) / 2; //how many spaces need to be printed in this current row

    int rowCount;
    for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < height; rowCount++) {
        char *ptr = trianglePattern[rowCount];
        int counter = 0;
        int astCounter = 0;
        int spCounter = 0;

        while (spCounter < spaces) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                strcpy(rowString, " ");
            }
            else {
                strcat(rowString, " ");
            }
            counter++;
            spCounter++;
        }

        while (astCounter < asteriskCount) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                strcpy(rowString, "*");
            }
            else {
                strcat(rowString, "*");
            }
            counter++;
            astCounter++;
        }

        spCounter = 0;
        while (spCounter < spaces) {
            strcat(rowString, " ");
            spCounter++;
        }

        asteriskCount+=2;
        spaces--;
        strcpy(ptr, rowString);
        //printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[rowCount]);
        //printf("%s\n", rowString);
    }
}

else {
    fractalTriangle(height/2, fractalLevel - 1);
    printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[0]);
    printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[1]);
    printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[2]);
    printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[3]);

}
```

}

Why would the array reset? I can't imagine it'd be a scope issue since the array itself is declared within the function. The purpose is to print a fractal triangle so there's no need to pass a 2D array to the function, I just want to create the pattern recursively. I'm doing this bit by bit (recursion still incomplete)- right now I'm just testing to see whether the array holds from call-to-call.

Comment: In fact it actually prints garbage values after the first recursion, as if it wasn't ever initialized in the first place.

Comment: Since the array trianglePattern is local to the fractalTriangle routine, and not declared 'static', each recursive call works on its own, uninitialized, local version of the array, and the results will not be propagated back the way you expect.

Comment: Does the expression *local variable* ring a bell?

Answer (score 3):

Since you define the array inside the function scope, each function creates a new 2D character array on the stack.  The function will operate on *that* instance of the 2D character array only.  By the time the recursion exists, the original un-modified 2D character array is printed.

You need to define a character array outside of the recursive function, then pass that character array (or rather a pointer to it) into the recursive function.

Comment: Or possibly use a global character array - by defining it outside of the function.  Which would be the easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is supposed to do, but here's what it *does*:

Your first (outer) call to the recursive function (from `main`) is:

```
fractalTriangle(height, 1);
```

Inside the function, you skip the first `if` statement since `fractalLevel == 1` and in the `else` part you call the function again, recursively, with `fractalLevel == 0`.

That call won't go into another recursive call, and won't print anything.

Once the recursive call returns, back in the first level (the one called from main), execution continues with:

```
printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[0]);
printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[1]);
printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[2]);
printf("%s\n", trianglePattern[3]);
```

but `trianglePattern` was not initialized at all (immediately went into the `else` part), so you print garbage.

Comment: But why wouldn't the first recursive call (fractalLevel == 0) modify the values of the array initialized before either of the if-else statements?

Comment: Because it's a different call, with different stack and different "instance" of `trianglePattern`. If you want to share that between calls, you need to put it somewhere global, or pass it around.